# Identify visible list in a button

Tags: c#, indexing, listbox

I am creating a program that will provide a front end to open files from server locations without having to navigate to server locations. The program has buttons that open lists for certain categories, then a single button to open the file from the currently selected item from the list.

My current issue is being able to identify which ListBox is currently in view, so that the program knows which list to use as a reference to open the right file.

Is there a way to create an "object" called "List", then assign the listbox to it and reference it? It does not seem to like what I have done.

```
 object ListBox;
 int IdCheck =  0;
 string DriveLoc;

 private void ButtAirInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GBAirInfo.Visible = true;
        GBAir.Visible = false;
        ListBox = LBAirInfo; //Here is where I load the List on to the screen, then 
                             //assign the list to the object ListBox
    }
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Files", connection))
        {
            DataTable FilesTable = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(FilesTable);

            if (ListBox.SelectedIndex == -1)
                MessageBox.Show("No Items selected");
            else
                IdCheck = ListBox.SelectedIndex;
                DriveLoc = (FilesTable.Rows[IdCheck]["Location"].ToString());
            if (DriveLoc == "")
                    MessageBox.Show("Item does not have a location");
            else
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@DriveLoc);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so my own research has found that you can assign a listbox to a generic term using -

```
Listbox ListBx

this.ListBx = Listbox1;
```

This way, I can ensure one piece of code will work for all Listboxes, and all I need to do is change the Listbox assigned to ListBx when I load each List through buttons. I hope this helps someone downt he line.